# How to only block images that are not cached using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension to save data and I need to block images. This can be easily done using the webRequest API and it works. But now I was wondering if I could just block images that are not in the cache, because if they are, it wouldn't have any significant difference on the data usage but only on the user inconvenience of not seeing the image that's there. Is there I can unblock cached images?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: use chrome.webRequest to redirect all images to a transparent 1x1 pixel while checking the cache via `fetch` in `only-if-cached` mode. If it succeeds, restore the original URL in the content script.

manifest.json:

- `permissions` should contain `"<all_urls>"`, `"webRequest"`, `"webRequestBlocking"`
- declare a content script and a background script

background.js (untested):

```js
const GIF_1x1 = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==';
const FETCH_OPTS = {
  cache: 'only-if-cached',
  mode: 'same-origin',
  method: 'HEAD',
};
const isCached = new Map();
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(info => {
  const {url} = info;
  if (!isCached.has(url)) {
    const data = {url, urlHash: '#' + encodeURIComponent(url)};
    fetch(url, FETCH_OPTS).then(() => {
      isCached.set(url, performance.now());
      setTimeout(() => isCached.delete(url), 1000);
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, {cmd: 'show', data}, {frameId: info.frameId});
    });
    return {redirectUrl: GIF_1x1 + data.urlHash};
  }
}, {
  types: ['image'],
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
}, ['blocking']);
```

content.js (untested):

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(({cmd, data}) => {
  if (cmd === 'show') {
    for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(`img[src^="data:"][src$="${data.urlHash}"]`)) {
      el.src = data.url;
    }
  }
});
```

Further enhancement would be to calculate the duration from cache-related HTTP headers and use it in setTimeout instead of 1000.